# How to do a conditional selection from macro variable in SAS

Tags: macros, sas, dataset

I have a dataset like this:

```
time    value
1990     22
1991     31
1992     21
1993     7
1994     32
```

And I have a macro variable contains several obs value.

`%put &p;` returns: `1 4 5`

I want to use this macro `&p` to select the matched time in default sequence.

The result should be this:

```
time    value
1990     22
1993     7
1994     32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data result;
   set indata;
   if _N_ in (&p);
run;
```

`_N_` is automatic variable containing incremental number of current data step iteration. Effectively it's number of current observation for simple cases like this. [More on Automatic Variables](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000695104.htm)